# Hide or remove the urlText field on the CKEditor Upload dialogue

Tags: ckeditor

I have stripped back the upload dialogue of CKEditor to make it a little less daunting for the average one finger user. I've utilised this code below to achieve this

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{ console.log(ev.data);
  // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
  // interested in (the 'image' dialog). This dialog name found using DevTools plugin
  if ( dialogName == 'image' )
  {
     // Remove the 'Link' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Image' dialog.
     dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
     dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );


    var uploadTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'Upload' );
    var uploadButton = uploadTab.get( 'uploadButton' );
    uploadButton[ 'label' ] = 'Upload to your Media Gallery';


     // Get a reference to the 'Image Info' tab.
     var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

    // ADD OUR CUSTOM TEXT
    infoTab.add(
      {
        type : 'html',
        html : 'Click the button to select your image from your gallery,<br> or use the UPLOAD tab to upload a new image.'
      },
      'htmlPreview'
    );

    var imageButton = infoTab.get( 'browse' );
            imageButton[ 'label' ] = 'Select Image';

            //I HAVE DONE THIS TO HIDE BUT I WOULD LIKE TO REALLY HIDE!
            var urlField = infoTab.get( 'txtUrl' );
    urlField[ 'style' ] = 'display:none; width:0;';


     // Remove unnecessary widgets/elements from the 'Image Info' tab.         
    infoTab.remove( 'ratioLock' ); 
    infoTab.remove( 'txtHeight' );          
    infoTab.remove( 'txtWidth' );          
    infoTab.remove( 'txtBorder'); 
    infoTab.remove( 'txtHSpace'); 
    infoTab.remove( 'txtVSpace'); 
    infoTab.remove( 'cmbAlign' );  
    //CANT REMOVE IT AS IT IS REQUIRED BY THE CODE TO PREPARE THE PREVIEW WINDOW
            //infoTab.remove( 'txtUrl' ); 
    infoTab.remove( 'txtAlt' ); 
  }
});
```

This achieves nearly everything I want except for the urlText field. I have successfully made it invisible with the change to its style, but its containing element is still there, CKEditor uses loads of tables to layout its dialogues, which means it affects the layout of the other elements..see image, the orange box is where the now invisible urlText field lives.

If I use the remove method it disappears nicely and the layout resets but then the dialogue wont work, I believe because the preview area grabs the URL for the image from this field.

[CKEditor simplified upload dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2HZ1.png)

I cant seem to find a way that I can hide that element including all its surrounding containers. None of the methods I can find in the docs seem to work.

Any ideas..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `afterInit` or `[onLoad][1]` method like this:

```
if(dialogName == 'image') {

    //dialogDefinition.afterInit= function () {
    // or
    dialogDefinition.onLoad= function () {
        infoTab.remove( 'txtUrl' ); 
    }
}
```

Though, the `afterInit` method is no longer in the docs, I would give it a try ;)

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for the answer. This wont help though as I cant REMOVE the element as it breaks the upload dialogue. I think the element needs to be there as the preview window might extract the URL of the image from that element.

Comment: Wouldn't it help to simply hide the dialog (or css display:none) ?

Comment: Hiding via css is no good, already tried, as the containing table elements are still rendered and you end up with a screwed display.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this works to hide the url field, and nothing is broken
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;
            if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
                dialogDefinition.onLoad = function () {
                    this.getContentElement("info", "txtUrl").getElement().setStyle("display", "none");
                }
            }
        });
```